# Does altering column type corrupt the column's existing data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to change a column's datatype. The column of type VARCHAR has thousands of GUID values like look those shown below:

```
b1f4ff32-48d4-494e-a32c-044014cea9
bc5a1158-b310-49ff-a1f3-09d4f8707f69
4b7ebc9d-9fa1-42d9-811e-0b7b4b7297a
fc7ba848-98ea-4bc6-add7-11f0ee9c6917a21
485741ff-2ab2-4705-91b3-136389948b7c
```

I need to convert the column type to `unqiqueidentifier` using the script below. Can I do that safely without corrupting the column data?

```
alter table MyTable
alter column guidColumn uniqueidentifier not null
```

Comment: Well, uh, at least one of those values is not a valid GUID. Did you try `SELECT guidColumn FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE guidColumn IS NOT NULL AND TRY_CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, guidColumn) IS NULL;`?

Comment: You can safely make a backup !-)

Comment: (Based on just the 5 values you've shown us, I can [already prove that your `ALTER` will fail](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2805a3544d266b561162e55850e86902). This is one of the consequences of making poor data type choices. Note that there is a potential for data loss, too, in a way - values too short will fail to convert, but values that are too long (like `fc7ba848-98ea-4bc6-add7-11f0ee9c6917a21`) will happily get silently truncated to `fc7ba848-98ea-4bc6-add7-11f0ee9c6917`, which may or may not be the desired outcome depending on why that value is too long.)

Comment: Create a new column and populate it with an `update`. Verify the values, e.g. by converting the new column values back to the original type and comparing to the original column. When you're satisfied, delete the original column and rename the new one.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the data type SQL Server will first check if *all* the values in the columns can be implicitly converted to the new data type; if they cannot then the `ALTER` will fail. If they can, then they will be implicitly converted and the `ALTER` will be successful (assuming no dependencies of course).

For a `uniqueidentifier` then either it's a valid value or it's not, so either the data will all convert or the `ALTER` won't take place. For something like a date and time data type, however, you could very easily end up with incorrect data if the data is stored in an ambiguous format like `dd/MM/yyyy`. This could mean a value like `'12/05/2022'` ends up being stored as the `date` value `2022-12-05` rather than `2022-05-12`. For such scenarios you would therefore want to `UPDATE` the data to an unambiguous format first, and then `ALTER` the data type of the column.

Answer (score 0):

The **uniqueidentifier** type is considered a character type for the purposes of conversion from a character expression, and therefore is subject to the truncation rules for converting to a character type.

**Also there are limitations,  uniqueidentifier type is limited to 36 char**

So if you decide to truncate the table like in this example:

```
DECLARE @ID NVARCHAR(max) = N'0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0wrong';  

SELECT @ID, CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, @ID) AS TruncatedValue;
```

This will be the result:

| String | Truncated Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0wrong | 0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0 |

So, if your string is more or less than 36 it will not truncate correctly.

For more information check Microsoft documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: The OP, however, has values that are *less* than 36 characters; those are going to be an issue. A `uniqueidentifier` must be *exactly* 36 characters; truncation'll occur if the value is longer, but you can't add characters to a string that don't exist.